# How do I hide (not remove) the content of a Panel (or any Container) in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm extending a `Panel` to build a custom component. Without knowing what this will contain later, how can I add a method to temporarily hide all contents and displaying an internal object (which is normally invisible) instead?

That is, is there a better way than

```
for each (var ui:DisplayObject in this.getChildren()) {
  ui.visible = false;
}
```

What I would love to do is swapping out the root content pane, but I don't know how to access it. Like this:

```
this._tempStore = this.removeChild(this.rootContentPaneObject);
this.rootContentPaneObject = this._myTemporaryReplacement;
```

Effectively, I'm trying to build a component which acts as a dropin replacement for a `Panel` but which behaves similar to a `ViewStack`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it might be easer to place a ViewStack within your Panel and use the stack to show / hide the appropriate content.

Comment: Yes, that was my first approach, but it opens up a whole new can of worms. It means you have to override all methods that deal with children to delegate them to the `ViewStack`'s child that takes the user-added subcomponents. I might eventually do it anyway, but my first attempt brought up a number of weird errors.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `Container.contentPane`. Note that it is `mx_internal`, so we are diving into Flex internals here (at your own risk...).

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
...
    this.mx_internal::contentPane.visible = false;
```

Next question is then how do you add children which are still visible (not in the contentPane). You might have to use `Container.rawChildren` for that.

Comment: I also found that digging into the source code, but I'd rather avoid that path. Adding to the chrome (the "internal" children) via `rawChildren` works well and is well documented, for example in "Flex 3: Training from the source", available at Safari Books Online.